# How to subset data in R

Tags: r, subset

So this is an insanely easy question but I have no idea why I'm getting an error.

I have two datasets 501 and 287.

501 has 501 obs. 296 variables

287 has 287 obs. 252 variables

I am trying to subset the data to have a new dataframe of just one column of data.

So the code i have is

```
A <- subset(Data_501[,290])
B <- subset(Data_287[,246])
```

Simple enough creating a new dataframe based on just one of the columns

However, The following happens when running it

```
> A <- subset(Data_501[,290])
> B <- subset(Data_287[,246])
Error in subset.default(Data_287[, 246]) : 
  argument "subset" is missing, with no default
```

I have no idea why the first one works perfectly fine, but the second line throws out this error. Any idea?

Edit:

```
> str(Data_287)
'data.frame':   287 obs. of  252 variables:
 $ P1                     : int  5 5 3 6 7 5 6 7 6 1 ...
 $ P2                     : int  5 5 5 4 5 5 4 2 5 1 ...
 $ P3                     : int  4 3 5 4 7 5 3 3 5 1 ...
 $ P4                     : int  3 5 3 3 7 4 2 5 5 1 ...
 $ P5                     : int  3 2 2 1 4 4 2 5 1 1 ...
 $ P6                     : int  2 5 4 1 6 4 2 5 5 1 ...
 $ P7                     : int  2 2 3 1 5 3 2 4 1 1 ...
 $ P8                     : num  3 3 3 1 6 4 2 6 3 1 ...
 $ P9                     : int  2 5 2 4 7 3 5 5 4 1 ...
 $ P10                    : int  2 3 6 2 7 5 3 2 5 1 ...
 $ P11                    : int  3 5 1 3 6 3 2 5 4 1 ...
 $ P12                    : num  2 3 4 3 7 3 2 1 3 3 ...
 $ P13                    : int  2 6 5 3 6 5 2 2 3 1 ...
 $ P14                    : int  4 6 3 4 6 3 4 2 5 1 ...
 $ P15                    : int  6 6 5 2 7 3 6 6 6 1 ...
 $ P16                    : num  2 5 7 3 5 4 4 4 7 7 ...
 $ P17                    : int  2 3 6 7 1 6 2 6 5 1 ...
 $ P18                    : num  3 5 6 6 5 6 4 4 7 7 ...
 $ P19                    : num  4 4 6 3 6 6 4 3 7 7 ...
 $ P20                    : num  3 3 6 2 6 6 3 4 5 3 ...
 $ P21                    : int  4 2 3 3 6 3 2 5 5 1 ...
 $ P22                    : int  2 2 5 4 7 2 3 6 5 1 ...
 $ P23                    : int  5 3 5 2 7 5 3 4 5 1 ...
 $ P24                    : num  3 2 5 1 6 3 4 4 1 2 ...
 $ P25                    : int  6 3 4 3 3 4 6 4 5 1 ...
 $ P26                    : int  6 3 4 5 2 5 5 4 7 5 ...
 $ P27                    : num  6 5 6 3 2 3 5 3 4 4 ...
 $ P28                    : num  3 3 5 3 3 3 4 2 5 7 ...
 $ P29                    : int  5 2 2 1 1 5 2 5 5 1 ...
 $ P30                    : int  3 2 5 2 3 5 4 2 3 1 ...
 $ P31                    : num  4 3 3 1 6 2 3 2 4 3 ...
 $ P32                    : num  4 3 4 2 3 4 3 2 3 4 ...
 $ P33                    : int  7 2 4 2 3 4 5 5 4 4 ...
 $ P34                    : int  6 3 4 5 3 4 5 5 5 1 ...
 $ P35                    : int  7 2 3 2 5 4 6 6 4 4 ...
 $ P36                    : num  6 3 3 4 2 4 3 3 3 7 ...
 $ P37                    : int  4 2 3 5 2 2 6 5 7 4 ...
 $ P38                    : int  5 2 3 3 2 2 5 7 7 4 ...
 $ P39                    : int  2 3 4 6 2 1 5 6 7 6 ...
 $ P40                    : num  5 2 3 2 2 2 3 2 1 4 ...
 $ P41                    : int  5 5 5 6 5 5 6 5 6 4 ...
 $ P42                    : int  5 3 5 5 3 4 6 6 5 1 ...
 $ P43                    : int  5 5 5 2 3 6 3 4 1 1 ...
 $ P44                    : int  1 2 5 2 1 5 3 3 5 1 ...
 $ P45                    : int  6 2 4 2 2 2 5 5 6 1 ...
 $ P46                    : int  4 6 6 4 3 4 6 6 6 7 ...
 $ P47                    : int  7 4 5 5 3 3 5 6 5 7 ...
 $ P48                    : int  6 5 6 2 2 3 7 5 6 7 ...
 $ P49                    : int  6 6 3 5 5 6 6 4 7 4 ...
 $ P50                    : int  3 5 4 6 1 5 6 4 6 4 ...
 $ P51                    : int  3 5 5 7 5 5 5 5 6 5 ...
 $ P52                    : int  4 6 5 7 7 5 5 5 6 4 ...
 $ P53                    : int  4 6 2 7 7 6 5 5 5 4 ...
 $ P54                    : int  6 3 3 6 6 6 5 6 5 4 ...
 $ P55                    : num  6 5 6 7 4 6 4 3 5 7 ...
 $ P56                    : num  5 5 3 4 6 6 5 6 6 4 ...
 $ P57                    : int  7 6 3 5 6 5 5 6 5 1 ...
 $ P58                    : int  7 6 3 6 7 4 6 7 6 1 ...
 $ P59                    : num  6 5 5 4 7 4 3 3 6 7 ...
 $ P60                    : num  3 5 6 7 7 2 3 7 7 3 ...
 $ P61                    : num  3 5 3 4 4 7 5 2 4 1 ...
 $ P62                    : num  5 3 3 3 3 4 4 2 2 4 ...
 $ P63                    : num  5 5 3 4 4 4 3 4 2 4 ...
 $ P64                    : num  2 3 3 3 4 5 5 2 2 7 ...
 $ P65                    : int  6 5 3 5 5 5 5 5 6 1 ...
 $ P66                    : num  6 6 5 7 4 5 6 3 7 7 ...
 $ P67                    : num  6 6 5 6 5 7 5 6 5 4 ...
 $ P68                    : num  6 6 5 6 5 5 6 4 7 4 ...
 $ P69                    : int  2 5 6 4 7 5 5 4 1 1 ...
 $ P70                    : int  3 5 2 1 6 7 4 6 1 1 ...
 $ P71                    : num  3 5 6 6 7 5 6 4 6 7 ...
 $ P72                    : num  2 5 3 1 4 4 3 4 1 1 ...
 $ P73                    : int  3 3 3 4 3 3 6 4 6 7 ...
 $ P74                    : int  5 3 5 4 3 2 6 6 5 1 ...
 $ P75                    : int  3 3 5 2 4 2 6 4 5 4 ...
 $ P76                    : num  3 3 4 5 1 2 6 6 4 7 ...
 $ P77                    : num  7 5 5 4 3 3 5 6 5 7 ...
 $ P78                    : num  7 5 5 5 5 3 6 7 5 7 ...
 $ P79                    : num  7 6 5 5 2 3 5 7 6 7 ...
 $ P80                    : num  6 6 6 6 6 6 6 3 7 6 ...
 $ P81                    : int  6 6 6 3 7 2 5 6 6 1 ...
 $ P82                    : int  6 5 6 6 7 2 6 6 7 1 ...
 $ P83                    : num  6 6 6 5 7 2 6 4 7 7 ...
 $ P84                    : num  5 4 6 6 6 3 3 6 5 7 ...
 $ P85                    : num  6 5 6 7 4 5 5 2 7 7 ...
 $ P86                    : num  3 5 5 7 4 6 7 4 7 7 ...
 $ P87                    : num  7 6 5 6 7 4 6 3 6 7 ...
 $ P88                    : num  6 3 5 7 4 6 2 3 4 7 ...
 $ P89                    : num  3 3 6 6 7 3 4 6 3 7 ...
 $ P90                    : num  2 3 4 4 5 4 3 2 3 1 ...
 $ P91                    : num  2 2 5 4 7 4 3 2 3 2 ...
 $ P92                    : num  3 6 5 1 5 7 4 4 7 7 ...
 $ P93                    : int  6 6 5 7 7 2 5 6 4 1 ...
 $ P94                    : int  7 6 5 7 7 3 3 7 3 1 ...
 $ P95                    : num  3 5 5 6 7 2 5 4 6 1 ...
  [list output truncated]
> str(Data_501)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   501 obs. of  296 variables:
 $ P1                     : num  7 7 6 5 6 4 6 5 5 2 ...
 $ P2                     : num  6 7 3 3 6 5 6 5 3 2 ...
 $ P3                     : num  4 6 3 4 3 3 3 3 2 1 ...
 $ P4                     : num  6 7 5 5 6 3 7 4 4 2 ...
 $ P5                     : num  6 6 5 4 4 3 7 4 3 2 ...
 $ P6                     : num  6 7 5 5 4 4 7 5 3 3 ...
 $ P7                     : num  6 7 5 4 6 3 6 4 3 2 ...
 $ P8                     : num  6 7 6 5 4 3 7 5 3 2 ...
 $ P9                     : num  6 4 2 3 4 3 6 4 3 1 ...
 $ P10                    : num  6 3 4 2 5 3 7 2 2 2 ...
 $ P11                    : num  6 4 3 3 5 4 6 4 3 1 ...
 $ P12                    : num  3 3 5 3 5 4 6 2 2 2 ...
 $ P13                    : num  5 6 3 7 6 4 5 4 4 2 ...
 $ P14                    : num  7 7 6 5 6 4 3 7 2 4 ...
 $ P15                    : num  7 4 5 5 6 3 5 4 5 4 ...
 $ P16                    : num  7 7 5 7 6 5 6 5 3 5 ...
 $ P17                    : num  4 5 3 1 5 2 6 2 3 3 ...
 $ P18                    : num  3 6 5 3 5 3 6 4 3 4 ...
 $ P19                    : num  3 5 6 3 4 3 6 5 3 3 ...
 $ P20                    : num  3 4 6 1 4 4 6 4 2 3 ...
 $ P21                    : num  6 7 3 6 4 3 3 4 3 1 ...
 $ P22                    : num  6 7 5 5 6 2 5 4 2 2 ...
 $ P23                    : num  6 5 3 4 4 3 6 2 3 1 ...
 $ P24                    : num  6 6 5 4 3 1 2 3 3 2 ...
 $ P25                    : num  2 1 3 3 2 3 1 5 3 7 ...
 $ P26                    : num  2 4 4 2 2 4 3 4 4 6 ...
 $ P27                    : num  1 1 5 3 3 4 2 5 3 6 ...
 $ P28                    : num  2 3 5 3 2 5 3 3 3 4 ...
 $ P29                    : num  2 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 5 ...
 $ P30                    : num  1 1 2 3 2 3 1 3 4 6 ...
 $ P31                    : num  2 3 5 3 2 3 1 1 4 4 ...
 $ P32                    : num  2 2 3 1 2 4 1 2 2 5 ...
 $ P33                    : num  6 6 5 4 6 4 6 5 6 7 ...
 $ P34                    : num  6 5 5 3 6 4 5 2 5 5 ...
 $ P35                    : num  7 7 5 5 6 5 6 5 6 6 ...
 $ P36                    : num  6 6 5 4 6 5 4 6 6 6 ...
 $ P37                    : num  6 2 5 4 6 4 3 6 2 6 ...
 $ P38                    : num  6 2 5 4 5 4 2 5 2 6 ...
 $ P39                    : num  3 3 5 5 6 4 5 5 2 6 ...
 $ P40                    : num  6 1 6 3 3 3 1 4 4 4 ...
 $ P41                    : num  4 4 3 6 5 4 3 3 5 5 ...
 $ P42                    : num  3 4 2 6 3 3 4 2 4 5 ...
 $ P43                    : num  2 2 3 1 3 1 5 2 4 2 ...
 $ P44                    : num  2 3 3 2 2 1 6 1 2 4 ...
 $ P45                    : num  6 1 4 6 3 3 1 4 2 7 ...
 $ P46                    : num  2 5 5 6 5 5 4 3 4 7 ...
 $ P47                    : num  3 4 5 6 6 4 3 5 4 7 ...
 $ P48                    : num  2 3 4 6 3 3 2 5 5 6 ...
 $ P49                    : num  2 6 5 7 6 7 7 5 4 5 ...
 $ P50                    : num  2 5 3 6 5 5 7 4 4 4 ...
 $ P51                    : num  2 7 3 7 4 7 3 5 3 2 ...
 $ P52                    : num  5 7 2 7 4 5 5 5 5 4 ...
 $ P53                    : num  4 2 5 6 5 4 7 5 5 5 ...
 $ P54                    : num  6 4 2 6 5 6 7 6 6 6 ...
 $ P55                    : num  4 4 3 7 5 3 5 1 3 5 ...
 $ P56                    : num  6 3 5 6 5 7 7 4 2 5 ...
 $ P57                    : num  6 7 3 7 6 1 7 3 6 6 ...
 $ P58                    : num  2 4 5 7 6 1 7 4 5 5 ...
 $ P59                    : num  2 6 6 6 6 1 6 3 4 6 ...
 $ P60                    : num  2 7 6 6 3 1 7 5 3 4 ...
 $ P61                    : num  1 2 3 5 2 4 3 2 2 3 ...
 $ P62                    : num  2 2 5 5 2 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ P63                    : num  2 2 5 5 2 3 2 3 3 4 ...
 $ P64                    : num  4 4 5 6 2 5 6 2 6 4 ...
 $ P65                    : num  5 5 5 6 6 5 5 5 6 5 ...
 $ P66                    : num  4 7 4 6 5 6 6 4 6 5 ...
 $ P67                    : num  3 5 5 4 3 5 6 3 6 3 ...
 $ P68                    : num  3 4 4 6 4 7 6 4 6 5 ...
 $ P69                    : num  1 1 2 4 2 1 6 4 6 2 ...
 $ P70                    : num  1 4 4 6 6 7 4 4 6 2 ...
 $ P71                    : num  2 1 2 4 2 3 6 2 7 2 ...
 $ P72                    : num  1 1 2 2 2 1 3 2 4 1 ...
 $ P73                    : num  1 4 4 5 4 2 3 5 4 6 ...
 $ P74                    : num  2 5 4 5 4 3 5 5 5 6 ...
 $ P75                    : num  2 5 4 4 3 1 3 5 4 6 ...
 $ P76                    : num  1 4 5 4 3 1 3 5 4 4 ...
 $ P77                    : num  6 6 6 7 6 7 5 6 5 7 ...
 $ P78                    : num  6 7 5 7 7 7 5 7 4 7 ...
 $ P79                    : num  5 6 6 7 6 7 5 6 5 7 ...
 $ P80                    : num  6 3 7 7 6 7 5 6 5 6 ...
 $ P81                    : num  5 7 6 7 6 4 6 4 5 6 ...
 $ P82                    : num  2 5 5 6 6 5 5 5 5 7 ...
 $ P83                    : num  3 5 6 7 6 4 6 5 4 7 ...
 $ P84                    : num  6 6 6 7 6 5 5 6 5 6 ...
 $ P85                    : num  7 3 5 7 6 7 6 6 4 7 ...
 $ P86                    : num  6 3 3 7 4 6 2 7 5 7 ...
 $ P87                    : num  2 3 5 6 6 7 1 6 5 7 ...
 $ P88                    : num  5 3 5 6 6 6 5 6 3 7 ...
 $ P89                    : num  4 4 6 6 3 4 3 7 3 4 ...
 $ P90                    : num  6 4 7 4 5 3 6 3 3 3 ...
 $ P91                    : num  6 5 7 4 5 4 7 3 3 4 ...
 $ P92                    : num  6 6 7 4 6 4 3 6 4 4 ...
 $ P93                    : num  5 4 4 6 7 4 5 4 5 6 ...
  [list output truncated]
```

Comment: Mind sharing the output of `str(Data_501)` and `str(Data_287)` ?

Comment: I've added it to the edit above.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what `subset()` is working for. You can check the example part of its document.

Comment: Rereading the question I think you're just willing `B <- Data_287[,246]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the subset operator `[` for data.frames by default drops unnecessary dimensions, so doing `Data_501[,290]` will give you a vector, not a data.frame. For that you need to add `drop = FALSE` like so:

```
A <- Data_501[, 290, drop = FALSE]
B <- Data_287[, 246, drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: `Data_501[, 290, drop = FALSE]` is equivalent to `Data_501[290]`.